# Use Serilog multiple sinks ReadFrom.Configuration

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

I am trying to set up serilog on a web service to write logs to both Microsoft Application Insights and to a file. The idea being that we will write everything to a log file but exception and error level events will go to the application insights. I am very new to using Application Insights but it looks like the App. Insights is receiving events, but not the "Traces" that contain the log statements. But I may misunderstand how this all works, as I said, very new.

What I am looking to do is set up a single logger in the code and have Serilog send to both sinks.  And I would like to set this up with ReadFrom.Configuration preferably instead of setting it up in the code, so to speak. My appsettings.json Serilog section is included below.

The configuration below works for logging to file, but does not seem to be sending anything to the Application Insights Trace.

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
          "instrumentationKey": "-inst-key-"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "flushToDiskInterval": "00:00:01",
          "path": "Logs\\myWebService-.log",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 50100100,
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 5,
          "buffered": false,
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {Level:u3} tid={ThreadId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

public Serilog.ILogger CreateLogger(IConfiguration config)
        {

            // Binding the class AppSettings to the AppSettings tage in the file: appsettings.json
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(appSettings);
            //CreateEventSource();
            // When nswag run, Configuration will be null. return an empty logger.
            if (config == null)
                return Log.Logger;
            return new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                                            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                                            .CreateLogger();
        }
```

Comment: What's kind of the web project, .NET core or something else? And please also include the code section in the post.

Comment: The project is .Net Core 2.2 and the code snippet with the ReadFrom.Configuration call is just below the config section.